# Google web-font, Open Sans's tilde rendering as a dash when the font size is 13px

Tags: webfonts

I'm using Google's Open Sans web-font as the main font in my website and it's rendering all the tilde character `(~)` as normal dashes while I'm using `13px` as `font-size`

[image: Tildes as dashes]

Is there a way to fix this without increasing `font-size`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found few methods to fix this issue.

1. Using `<em>~</em>`

[image: Fixed tildes with em]

2. Using `<span class='tilde'>~</span>` and applying some CSS like below:

`.tilde { font-size: 14px !important; }`

[image: Fixed tildes with span]

Answer (score 3):

Use the full width tilde character.

Full width tile: ～

Regular tilde: ~

HTML escape codes: &#65374; &#xff5e;

http://www.charbase.com/ff5e-unicode-fullwidth-tilde

Answer (score 1):

#### Update: fixed

[Download fixed version here.](https://github.com/googlefonts/opensans/tree/main/fonts/variable)

It's fixed in [version 3.000](https://github.com/google/fonts/pull/2997)! Which you can download from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?preview.text_type=custom&preview.text=%7E%7E%7E%7E#standard-styles) or [their github](https://github.com/googlefonts/opensans/tree/main/fonts/variable).

---

#### Original:

[It's a known bug in Open Sans.](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/399) It was apparently fixed internally two years ago tomorrow, and the fix will be released “Hopefully in Q1 2020.”

FWIW, I see the same problem in MS Office at 2, 7, and 10, but not 13.

Answer (score -1):

You can try a different font or font-family. For instance, the below fixes this problem at `13px`:

```
font-family: cursive;
```